# Storybook StoryRouter story is marked as required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am using React with Storybook. One of my components uses Link and react need that any Link component should be wrapped in Router, that is why I am using the npm module `StoryRouter`. Everything works fine but I get one alert on the console.

```
// simple ListItem.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
export const ListItem = () => {
    return (
        <Link to={{pathname:`/page/1`}}>
            go to page
        </Link>
    );
}

// ListItem.stories.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import StoryRouter from 'storybook-react-router';
import { ListItem } from "./ListItem";
let props = {
    text:"Introduction to limits",
}
storiesOf("ListItem", module)
    .addDecorator(StoryRouter()) // this causes the alert
    .add("default", () => <ListItem {...props} />)
```

And when I view the component on getStorybook, there is a message on the console

```
    Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `story` is marked as required in `StoryRouter`, but its value is `undefined`.
        in StoryRouter (created by storyFn)
        in storyFn
        in ErrorBoundar
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade storybook-react-router to 1.0.8.  This bug has been fixed.  See: https://github.com/gvaldambrini/storybook-router/issues/43